# Drawing a smooth, pixelated line in Android

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas, paint, antialiasing

What I'm trying to get:

[image]

What I'm getting:

[image]

I'm drawing by connecting two consecutive coordinates with:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
paint.setStrokeWidth(75);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

// Tried without success:
paint.setAntiAlias(false);

// Also tried without success:
paint.setAntiAlias(true);

// Loop list<Point>; keep track of previous Point
canvas.drawLine(xPrev, yPrev, x, y, paint);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `paint.setAntiAlias(true);` to get smooth effect.

Or use `paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(/*args*/));` for blur effect.

Also make sure hardware acceleration is turned off from the Android manifest.

If it is not still as expected, use anti alias while drawing, then scale down and scale up, or if possible draw small sized path and scale it up.

Comment: Output is the same.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work unless you use software rendering.

Comment: Yeah, That's what I meant by telling to turn off hardware acceleration.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);` and `paint.setStrokeJoin()`. Hope it helps